# In automator, using applescript, how can I append a folder name to a selected path correctly?

Tags: path, applescript, append, automator

This automator script is an example.  When i display the path it looks correct, but if i then try to copy files to that path I get an error.

[image: example automator script]

Comment: I don't think that you need either action "Set Value of Variable".  Not that I can see (unless you use the variables later on in the workflow that isn't shown.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the fix - needed posix paths.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set theFilePath to POSIX path of (input as string) & "/Samples" as string
    display dialog theFilePath

    return theFilePath
end run
```